# IIS express doesn't start but Kestrel web server instead

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

My application have been working well for weeks. Today I possibly did something wrong and IIS express is not starting any more (and no errors in the event log) but Kestrel appears in a command window saying it is listening for connections on 5000th port.
How to fix it and get IIS express back?

Startup.cs:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            // This will push telemetry data through Application Insights pipeline faster, allowing you to view results immediately.
            builder.AddApplicationInsightsSettings(developerMode: true);
        }
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);

        services.AddMvc();

        // Add functionality to inject IOptions<T>
        services.AddOptions();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        app.UseApplicationInsightsRequestTelemetry();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseBrowserLink();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: could you show us `Startup` class?

Comment: @ivamax9 yes, updated post

Comment: in vs there is a dropdown in the toolbar where you select IISExpress or the command line way to launch the app

Comment: if nothing helps, delete .vs directory (it contains iisexpress settings among other things). Also don't add tags to title and on top of that issue is not .NET Core related at all

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I still do not have any logical explanation but I accidentally fixed it. I discovered that it work on any different TCP port. It has been working for all times on 46394 but now can't start on it but starts well on any different. I netstat'ed and saw no concurrent listener on that port but for some reason iis express no more works on it. The worst thing is that no any error logs on that. Anyways it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `Properties/launchSettings.json` file. It contains "configuration" for VS "Run" button (it dropdown menu), like this:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:63104/",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "My Web App": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5000"
    }
  }
}
```